# Sqoop not returning the table Schema in sql server

Tags: sql-server, bash, sqoop

I  am trying to run sqoop command to get the SCHEMA of a table (ABC_XYZ) from SQL Server. But it's not returning the SCHEMA.

**Command that is being Executed :**

sqoop eval  --connect $conStr  --username $username  --password $password --query ""SELECT TABLE_CATALOG,TABLE_SCHEMA,TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where table_name = 'ABC_XYZ' ""

### **My Output :**

### | TABLE_CATALOG        | TABLE_SCHEMA         | TABLE_NAME           | COLUMN_NAME          | DATA_TYPE            |

---

**Desired Output :**

TABLE_CATALOG   TABLE_SCHEMA    TABLE_NAME      COLUMN_NAME   DATA_TYPE
test_database     dbo            ABC_XYZ          brand         nvarchar
test_database     dbo            ABC_XYZ          price         int
test_database     dbo            ABC_XYZ          first_name    nvarchar
test_database     dbo            ABC_XYZ          last_name     nvarchar
test_database     dbo            ABC_XYZ          age           int
test_database     dbo            ABC_XYZ          name          nvarchar
test_database     dbo            ABC_XYZ          age           int

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow. Please take a look at the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and especially at [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: Does `$conStr` mention the correct database?

Comment: Yes I am providing the correct database in $conStr